# Firewall settings causing 523 error [Linux]

Tags: linux, connection, iptables

I have a problem where I tried to add some firewall rules using iptables to allow connections to the MySQL database. That ended up being a mistake cause the whole website now displays a 523 Origin is unreachable error.

Here is a list of iptable rules.

```
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N FORWARD_IN_ZONES
-N FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE
-N FORWARD_OUT_ZONES
-N FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-N FORWARD_direct
-N FWDI_mysqlrule
-N FWDI_mysqlrule_allow
-N FWDI_mysqlrule_deny
-N FWDI_mysqlrule_log
-N FWDI_public
-N FWDI_public_allow
-N FWDI_public_deny
-N FWDI_public_log
-N FWDO_mysqlrule
-N FWDO_mysqlrule_allow
-N FWDO_mysqlrule_deny
-N FWDO_mysqlrule_log
-N FWDO_public
-N FWDO_public_allow
-N FWDO_public_deny
-N FWDO_public_log
-N INPUT_ZONES
-N INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-N INPUT_direct
-N IN_mysqlrule
-N IN_mysqlrule_allow
-N IN_mysqlrule_deny
-N IN_mysqlrule_log
-N IN_public
-N IN_public_allow
-N IN_public_deny
-N IN_public_log
-N OUTPUT_direct
-N ufw-after-forward
-N ufw-after-input
-N ufw-after-logging-forward
-N ufw-after-logging-input
-N ufw-after-logging-output
-N ufw-after-output
-N ufw-before-forward
-N ufw-before-input
-N ufw-before-logging-forward
-N ufw-before-logging-input
-N ufw-before-logging-output
-N ufw-before-output
-N ufw-logging-allow
-N ufw-logging-deny
-N ufw-not-local
-N ufw-reject-forward
-N ufw-reject-input
-N ufw-reject-output
-N ufw-skip-to-policy-forward
-N ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-N ufw-skip-to-policy-output
-N ufw-track-forward
-N ufw-track-input
-N ufw-track-output
-N ufw-user-forward
-N ufw-user-input
-N ufw-user-limit
-N ufw-user-limit-accept
-N ufw-user-logging-forward
-N ufw-user-logging-input
-N ufw-user-logging-output
-N ufw-user-output
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j INPUT_direct
-A INPUT -j INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-A INPUT -j INPUT_ZONES
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-before-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-after-logging-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-reject-input
-A INPUT -j ufw-track-input
-A INPUT -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_direct
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_IN_ZONES
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE
-A FORWARD -j FORWARD_OUT_ZONES
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-before-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-after-logging-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-reject-forward
-A FORWARD -j ufw-track-forward
-A OUTPUT -j OUTPUT_direct
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-before-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-after-logging-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-reject-output
-A OUTPUT -j ufw-track-output
-A FORWARD_IN_ZONES -g FWDI_public
-A FORWARD_IN_ZONES_SOURCE -s 0.0.0.0/32 -g FWDI_mysqlrule
-A FORWARD_OUT_ZONES -g FWDO_public
-A FORWARD_OUT_ZONES_SOURCE -d 0.0.0.0/32 -g FWDO_mysqlrule
-A FWDI_mysqlrule -j FWDI_mysqlrule_log
-A FWDI_mysqlrule -j FWDI_mysqlrule_deny
-A FWDI_mysqlrule -j FWDI_mysqlrule_allow
-A FWDI_mysqlrule -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_log
-A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_deny
-A FWDI_public -j FWDI_public_allow
-A FWDI_public -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A FWDO_mysqlrule -j FWDO_mysqlrule_log
-A FWDO_mysqlrule -j FWDO_mysqlrule_deny
-A FWDO_mysqlrule -j FWDO_mysqlrule_allow
-A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_log
-A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_deny
-A FWDO_public -j FWDO_public_allow
-A INPUT_ZONES -g IN_public
-A INPUT_ZONES_SOURCE -s 0.0.0.0/32 -g IN_mysqlrule
-A IN_mysqlrule -j IN_mysqlrule_log
-A IN_mysqlrule -j IN_mysqlrule_deny
-A IN_mysqlrule -j IN_mysqlrule_allow
-A IN_mysqlrule -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public -j IN_public_log
-A IN_public -j IN_public_deny
-A IN_public -j IN_public_allow
-A IN_public -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A IN_public_allow -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 138 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-input -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j ufw-skip-to-policy-input
-A ufw-after-logging-forward -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-after-logging-input -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-before-forward -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-forward -j ufw-user-forward
-A ufw-before-input -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 3 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 11 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 12 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p udp -m udp --sport 67 --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-not-local
-A ufw-before-input -d 224.0.0.251/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 5353 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -d 239.255.255.250/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 1900 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -j ufw-user-input
-A ufw-before-output -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-output -j ufw-user-output
-A ufw-logging-allow -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "
-A ufw-logging-deny -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j RETURN
-A ufw-logging-deny -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type LOCAL -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type MULTICAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m addrtype --dst-type BROADCAST -j RETURN
-A ufw-not-local -m limit --limit 3/min --limit-burst 10 -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-not-local -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-forward -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-input -j DROP
-A ufw-skip-to-policy-output -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-output -p tcp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-track-output -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -s 0.0.0.0/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -s 0.0.0.0/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 3306 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m udp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m multiport --dports 80,443 -m comment --comment "\'dapp_Apache%20Full\'" -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -m comment --comment "\'dapp_OpenSSH\'" -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-user-limit -m limit --limit 3/min -j LOG --log-prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
-A ufw-user-limit -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A ufw-user-limit-accept -j ACCEPT
```

I am using Linux Ubuntu 18.04
Multiple sources suggest that it likely is an error with DNS settings, but I doubt it cause it happened right after changing some of the firewall settings.

Using ping from external sources works just fine.
Using wget returns the 523 origin error.
However using wget from localhost returns a connection timed out.

I can confirm that restarting apache2 and Nginx works fine with no issues.

List of ports in use:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      27120/nginx: master 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      27086/apache2       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21829/perl          
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      410/systemd-resolve 
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      502/sshd            
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      27086/apache2       
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      27407/mariadbd      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6379          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      562/redis-server 12 
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      27120/nginx: master 
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      502/sshd            
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*                           21829/perl          
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           410/systemd-resolve
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok well I disabled iptables and it worked. Took me long enough to figure that out.